# Swift How To Use Animations To Fade In New Image and then Fade back to Old Image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I am currently creating a game based on the game "Simon Says" where the user has to press coloured buttons in the same order that the application showed previously. The sequence keeps getting longer and longer making it more and more difficult. I designed buttons in Illustrator (4 coloured buttons with both a pressed state and a normal state, so 8 images). I currently have 4 buttons and connected the normal state images to it. I now want to create an animation to change between the normal and pressed state to briefly show the user the button he needs to press and then to change back to it's normal state to show the next button the user needs to press in the sequence.

Here is my code:

```
   UIView.transition(with: currentButton, duration: 0.7, options: .autoreverse, animations: {
        switch currentButton.tag {
        case 1: currentButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "greenpressed"), for: .normal)
        case 2: currentButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "redpressed"), for: .normal)
        case 3: currentButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bluepressed"), for: .normal)
        case 4: currentButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "yellowpressed"), for: .normal)
        default:
            print("doPattern switch statement default")
        }
    }) { (complete) in
        if self.simonSays.currentButtonIndex == self.simonSays.getColorPattern.count - 1 {
            self.simonSays.currentButtonIndex = 0
            return self.patternIsFinished()
        }

        self.simonSays.currentButtonIndex += 1
        self.doPattern()
    }
```

This changes the state once to pressed but doesn't change it back to his normal state. I also tried to put a switch in the "complete" part of the animation but then the state didn't change at all. Is there a way to do this with animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to again reset the orignal image in `completion` of the animation, because you are `setting` the image. The animation may go back and forth, but the assigment has not been undone.

But before that you should animating the alpha value of the button inside the animation block. I don't thinking setting an image results in animation. Try this logic.

```
func animateButton(with image: UIImage, defaultImage: UIImage! = nil) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            button.alpha = 0
        }) { (completed) in
            button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
                button.alpha = 1
            }) {
                //Animate back only if current image is not default image
                if defaultImage != nil {
                    animateButton(with: defaultImage)
                } else {
                    // Your actual completion here
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now call this method with the required image and default image.

```
animateButton(requiredImage, defaultImage)
```

This is a very crude implementation of the logic i had in my head. But it will work.

Comment: I tried this already and then I see no animation at all. The normal state image just stays there without going to the pressed state. The user has no clue which button to press.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't quite work for me it seems. I changed the code a bit so that it works for the 4 buttons I have in my game but the animations are doing weird things now and sometimes keep pulsating :/

Comment: Can you show me how you implemented this method in your project?

Comment: I can but the code is too long to put in the comments, is there a way to share it easily? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178027/discussion-between-rakesha-shastri-and-frederic-vanderheyden).